# Error while installing stable-baselines in Kaggle

Tags: python, machine-learning, openai-api

i'm trying to run some machine learning environment on Kaggle, but i can't install the packages... I Need to install stable-baselines3[extra] but i cant. I tried with

```
pip install stable-baselines3[extra]
```

but i get this error:

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) 
after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection
object at 0x7f8159233e50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure 
in name resolution')': /simple/stable-baselines3/
```

How to resolve this?